# crreating a shell script to scroll through text files?

Tags: linux, shell

Trying to create the ability to scroll through a text file with a shell script.  Anyone have any pointers for how to build this?  I can easily [display a text file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-displaying-files-in-shell-script/):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/tmp/input.txt"
echo "*** File - $FILE contents ***"
cat $FILE
```

But I am looking for something with the features and display of commands along the bottom of a man file -- jump to top, jump to bottom, page up, page down, scroll line up, scroll line down.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dialog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807) does the trick

Answer (score 3):

Try less (it's better than more):

```
less filename
```

Comment: less is quite powerful, allowing navigating up/down, regex searching, etc, along with rereading a file to see if the file has grown.

Answer (score 2):

Erm ... that already exists.

`more MyFileName`

Comment: :-) I am looking for more on the features and display of the commands along the bottom of man file -- jump to top, jump to bottom, page up, page down, scroll line up, scroll line down...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really shell-script material.

Comment: I see;  I was hoping some unholy combination of clear and more|cat could do it.

Comment: Erm ... I'm not going to say that there's absolutely no way possible for the simple fact that I've seen people do some pretty insane things over the years but ... godspeed.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever's being used to display man files is also available to display anything else, depending on your system it may be `less` or `most`, `more` is just the most basic one.

If none of those do it, then maybe if you could post a screenshot of what you get when you view a manpage someone could identify it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is in fact a `most` command. Now someone needs to build `least` for symmetries sake.

Answer (score 0):

[Ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) is probably a better fit for your question. Might be worth exploring. I personally like ncurse programs within terminals.